# Auto Expiring Fields inside an Object in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Assume we have very heavy Java Object which is used in millions across process. The application size grows huge and we cannot store the actual objects.

```
Object A - uses X bytes (Heavy object)
```

Now, to reduce the memory footprint - We thought of storing serialized byteString for the object.

```
ByteString of A - uses X/10 bytes
```

This reduced memory footprint by 10 times, Now, this serialisation and de-serialization comes at a cost with performance. (Ignoring GC pauses and Allocating heavy in memory)

Now, mostly this conversion of byteString to actual object happens across the application quite frequently using getter methods and at a rapid rate for only very short duration. Let's say 2 sec and mostly it is never queried once processed.

Thought of wrapping the byteString to wrapper object

```
WrapperObject {

  ByteString byteString;
  ExpiringField actualProto; // this expires every 2 seconds.
 

  getObject(){
     if (actualProto == null) return convertAndCreateCache(byteString);
     return actualProto;
 
  }

}
```

This way only convert once the byteString conversion happens and we don't have huge memory footprint as it will be auto deleted after 2 seconds.

We can use CacheBuilder Map with expiry but it will create many maps inside object ?

Do we have any auto expiry field in java which can be garbage collected after some time ?

Comment: You might look at one of the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) classes perhaps

Comment: thank you very much! after reading about weak references think would be interesting use case for the above problem statement.

Comment: "collected after some time" - yes, `WeakReference`; but be aware. You have no idea when a GC cycle is going to reclaim the exact regions where your wet references might be. This means you have no real guarantees when this will actually happen.

Comment: Yes, Soft References are also good use case however using soft reference will hold up until the application is close to OOM so avoiding use of it. However we can flags on soft references with additional flag to control the the time. XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=2500. Hopefully I should see significant improvement!

Comment: reference link - https://www.baeldung.com/java-soft-references